# Exchange 2007: Auto reply message to senders (server side)

Tags: exchange-2007, auto-reply, email

I’ve a need to create an auto-reply for some of the users in my organization where, when a person sends an E-mail to e.g. user@myorg.com is faced with an automatically auto-reply with some message “closed during the holidays. We are back at… etc. etc. etc.”.

I’ve tried to create a Transport Rule on our Exchange server but the only option I can find in the actions-window is to reply with a “Bounce message to sender with enhanced status code” but I guess that is not the precise action I’m looking for.

How can I set up a server-side auto-reply, apply it to only a fixed number of users in my organization and create a message to the senders (which is outside the organization)?

Comment: Glen Scales has a script [here](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2009/08/setting-out-of-office-oof-with.html) that will do what you want.